# adding aspectj logging to java web application

Tags: java, logging, aspectj

I'm newbie at aspectj so my question may be ridiculous. I have a java web application and I want that print all running method name before and after. So I added an aspectj-1..7.4.jar and a class like below. But it doesn't print to log file. Is there anyting i forgot or what can i do? Thanx in advance.

```
@Aspect
 public class LogAspect {

 final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(LogAspect.class);

   @Pointcut("execution(* *.*(..))")
    public void defineEntryPoint() {
    }

    @Before("defineEntryPoint()")
    public void beforeMethod(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        log.error("Before" + joinPoint.getSignature());
        System.out.println("Before" + joinPoint.getSignature());

    }

    @After("defineEntryPoint()")
    public void afterMethod(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        log.error("After" + joinPoint.getSignature());
        System.out.println("After" + joinPoint.getSignature());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not printing to log file, but do you see  your system.out in your console?

I would suggest changing `execution(* *.*(..))` to `execution(* *(..))`

I don't know the packages of the class you are trying to intercept, but it seems to me that with `*.*(..)` you could only get the classes in anypackage.anyPackage

Comment: I don't see my console too.  I try `execution(* *(..))` it didn't work.

Comment: Are you using Spring?

Comment: Yes but i didn't integrate aspectj and spring.

Comment: If you can use spring, it's the best solution and easy to use.

Could you post part of your pom.xml?
Since you are not using spring, I think you should take a look at this:
http://ridgetopsolutions.com/blog/2013/02/12/getting-started-with-aspectj-and-maven/
You may be missing something in your pom.